# Copy record from one Oracle SQL table to another with extra columns

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

This is part of a larger Java program, but I'm looking for a way in Oracle SQL to copy a record from one table to another.  The original table is 45 columns.  The second table is an archive table of the original table.

EDIT - It has the same 45 columns, but also has a NewKey column - created in the archive table using

```
("NEWKEY" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1)
```

and an archive_date column

```
"ARCHIVEDATE" DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Is there a way to do a query a la

```
INSERT INTO Archive_Table A
SELECT * (plus NEWKEY, ARCHIVEDATE) FROM Original Table O
WHERE O.CUSTKEY = passed_param;
```

where the only parameter passed is the CUSTKEY?  Once a record is copied from the original table, it will then be deleted from the original table.

Comment: What was the results of your own testing?  You'll need to list the individual columns, and and change your WHERE clause.  There's no need for a join (WHERE A.CUSTKEY = O.CUSTKEYI), just 'where o.custkey = passed_parm. And you'll need to add a condition to prevent getting rows that you got on a previous run.

Comment: Let me edit it a bit to see if if makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARCHIVEDATE is a date field, so it should default to SYSDATE, not CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. This eliminates a conversion for every insert.

As others have said, just list out the columns:

```
insert into archivetable (custkey, cola, colb, colc) 
select custkey, cola, colb, colc 
  from originaltable 
 where custkey = passedparam;
```

There is no need to include NEWKEY or ARCHIVEDATE as they will be initialized on the insert.

Comment: Thank you Brian - this helps.  I'll see if they supes will let me change the ARCHIVEDATE to make this easier.

Answer (score -1):

If you started typing those 45 columns half an hour ago (when you posted the question), your code would have already be up and running.

Anyway: using an asterisk (`*`) in `select` is probably not the best idea; for what? What benefit do you expect? To save some keyboard strokes? Because, if you explicitly name all columns, you exactly know which value goes into which column. What if a new column is added into one of those two tables? `insert into select *` won't work any longer.

What you ask can be done using some dynamic SQL (so, within PL/SQL) by querying `user_tab_columns`, composing the `insert into` statement, paying attention to differences (identity and timestamp columns). Once you're done with coding and testing, as I said - a straightforward naming all those columns would be finished *ages* ago.

If I were you, I'd do exactly that: name all 45 columns.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot.  I always appreciate snark.

Comment: Sadly (for you), that's how it is :)